# What are some good username / vanity url rules?

Tags: url, dns, naming-conventions, vanity-url

This isn't about "how to" as much "how best".

I understand most sites with vanity urls have basic rules:

- >4 characters (covers a bunch of useful tokens like "blog" and "jobs", but also a long list of "4-letter words")
- start with alpha
- alphanumerics only (maybe ._- too, but user.name would be the same as username)
- disallow reserved words to prevent abuse and avoid confusion (ex: contact, about, username, vanityurl, [what are some others?])

What other rules are important to consider for a site adding vanity urls?

What are common words that should be reserved to prevent confusion or abuse?

Comment: This question has received some down votes.  Can someone help explain why?

Comment: perhaps because it is no concrete programming problem, and probably off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to begin posting what I've found so far.

**Set Character Limit >4 characters**

**Must contain at least one alpha [a-z]**

**Optional Special Characters: `._-`**

- Special characters should not count toward distinct tokens (i.e. `user.name` = `username`)
- Special characters should also not be used simultaneously (ex. `user..name`)
- Special characters should not start or end a token (ex. `-user-name-`, `.username-`)
- **UPDATE:** Facebook and Twitter disallow the dash as well. Consider excluding.
- Gmail only allows dots.

**Avoid character confusion by preventing similar looking characters** `l,1`, `o0`

- For example, if `colbert` is registered, prevent `co1bert` or `c01bert` from also being registered

**Case-insensitive**

**Reserved Word List**

```
about, aboutus, account, accounts, add, admin, administer, administrator, admins, ajax, anon, anonymous, apache, api, app, apps, archive, archives, article, articles, auth, authenticate, authentication, author, backup, better, blog, blogger, cache, careers, cart, changelog, checkout, client, clients, codereview, compare, config, configuration, connect, contact, contactus, contributor, cpanel, create, css, daemon, data, database, deal, deals, delete, director, direct_messages, docs, documentation, download, downloads, edit, editor, email, emailus, employment, enterprise, explore, facebook, faq, faqs, favorites, feed, feeds, fleet, fleets, follow, followers, following, font, fonts, forum, forums, friend, friends, friending, ftpuser, games, gist, group, groups, guest, help, home, host, hosting, hostmaster, http, httpd, idea, ideas, image, images, include, includes, index, indexes, info, invitation, invitations, invite, is, it, job, jobs, json, lib, library, list, lists, login, logout, logs, mail, map, maps, master, mine, mis, misc, miscellaneous, moderate, moderator, module, modules, mysql, news, nobody, node, nodes, oauth, oauth_clients, offers, office, openid, operate, operator, oracle, order, orders, organizations, owner, password, passwords, plans, poll, polls, popular, post, postgres, postmaster, president, privacy, profile, profiles, projects, public, put, pwnd, pwned, pwnage, question, questions, qwerty, rdf, recruit, recruiter, recruiters, recruitment, register, registrar, registration, remove, replies, root, rss, sales, save, save, script, scripts, search, security, server, service, sessions, settings, shell, shop, signup, signout, sitemap, spam, ssl, ssladmin, ssladministrator, sslwebmaster, stat, stats, statistics, status, stories, student, styleguide, subscribe, support, supporter, survey, surveys, sysadmin, template, templates, terms, test, tester, testing, tests, testuser, theme, themes, tour, tomcat, translations, trends, tutorial, tutorials, twitter, twittr, unfollow, unsubscribe, url, update, upload, uploads, user, users, video, videos, weather, webadmin, webmaster, widget, widgets, wiki, www, wwww, xfn, xmpp, yml, yaml
```

- Consider adding words commonly found in [brute force attacks](http://www.moehre.org/bruteforce.html#Username).

Answer (score 0):

While talking about vanity URL's keep 2 things in mind. If you are providing a product oriented website then optimize the product name in the URL. Or if your website is like social networking then optimize the user name, community name or group name in the Deep links.

http://hioxindia.com/checkAvailability.php